# Vlookup based on Text

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to build a vlookup macro, which offsets a number places depending on the currency in column F. The Lookup value is based on the date. I currently have a formulae in there and I just drag, however I am trying to do this via vba.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'FX Rates'!A:K,11,0)
```

[image]

Depending on the currency these are the number of places i need it to offset.

[image]

I tried to record a macro but it was not much help.

```
Sub test()
Dim Currency_EUR As String
Dim Lookup_Range As Range
Dim Currency_Rate As Single

Currency_EUR = Sheets("Recon").Range("F2")
Set Lookup_Range = Sheets("FX Rates").Range("A:K")

Currency_Rate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Currency_EUR, Lookup_Range, 2, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: What VBA do you have so far?

Comment: I tried to record one

Comment: So you are asking someone to write your code for you?

Comment: Where are you offsetting from and to? This seems like something that could be done with formulas alone. If you don't want to have to drag formulas set your data up as a table so autofill kicks in. Showing more of the dataset with an example with expected result would really help.

Comment: @AndyG I have a code I have been working on, so I need assistance in writing in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you could probably do this without looping, but I'm sure the following would work:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'change the sheet above to the one you are using
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'check the last row in Sheet1
For i = 2 To LastRow 'loop from row 2 to last
    CurrencyLookUp = ws.Cells(i, 6)
    Select Case CurrencyLookUp
        Case Is = "USD"
            OffsetPlace = 2
        Case Is = "CZK"
            OffsetPlace = 3
        Case Is = "DKK"
            OffsetPlace = 4
        Case Is = "GBP"
            OffsetPlace = 5
        Case Is = "SEK"
            OffsetPlace = 6
        Case Is = "NOK"
            OffsetPlace = 7
        Case Is = "AUD"
            OffsetPlace = 8
        Case Is = "CAD"
            OffsetPlace = 9
        Case Is = "GBP/USD"
            OffsetPlace = 10
        Case Is = "EUR"
            OffsetPlace = 11
    End Select
    ws.Cells(i, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4],'FX Rates'!C1:C11," & OffsetPlace & ",FALSE)"
    'above enter the formulas
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way without VBA.

set your data up as a table and have a named range called `currency` that holds the different abbreviations with a header. Then use the following formula which will autofill down your table (I have assumed will go in column G for now)

```
=VLOOKUP([@Date],'FX Rates'!A:K,MATCH([@CYY],currency,0),FALSE)
```

[image: Data with formula and named range (currency]

Named range `currency` in the above is `J4:J14`

Range being looked up against is:

[image: Lookup range]